# Softlayer Object Storage CDN access

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need restrict access to the files in the Object Storage.

Is it possible to open Object Storage CDN only for the selected IPs?

Or there is exist any other method to allow download files from Object Storage without authentication from the selected IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object storage of Softlayer is based in OpenStack. What I know in OpenStack there is not such option to only allow the access to a specific IP.

You can allow download the file without authentication using [temporal URLs](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/config-reference/content/object-storage-tempurl.html), but it does not have any option to restrict IPs (at least I do not know about that).

I think you could ask to the openstack forums about the IP restriction. if that is possible in OpenStack should be possible in softlayer object storage as well.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Since Object Storage uses s3, you can restrict the ACL of the object itself.
For instance, If you were using Amazon's Java SDK you could do:

```
AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
acl.grantPermission(new CanonicalGrantee("d25639fbe9c19cd30a4c0f43fbf00e2d3f96400a9aa8dabfbbebe1906Example"), Permission.ReadAcp);
acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read);
acl.grantPermission(new EmailAddressGrantee("user@email.com"), Permission.WriteAcp);

File file = new File(uploadFileName);
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file).withAccessControlList(acl));
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-using-java-sdk.html